# composing one function as a function of another function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have two functions: $f_1=\sum_i x_iy_i$ and $f_2=\sum_i x_iy_i^2$, where $x_i$s and $y_i$s are positive and smaller than $1$. I want to write one of them as a function of the other (for example $f_1=f_2/2$), but I can't find the relation. Is it possible to write one as a function of the other? Could anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems doubtful. You've got 2 equations in several unknowns, so unless there are additional relations there's just not much to be said.

Comment: One thing to note: you cannot write $f_2$ as $g \circ f_1$ for any linear function $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ since this would imply that $f_2 \colon \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is bilinear (since $f_1$ is just the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$), but $f_2$ is clearly not linear in the second argument.  This isn't necessarily saying much, though, since $g$ has the form $g(x)=ax$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If we to relax the conditions to $x_i, y_i \in [0, 1]$, instead of $(0, 1)$, we could take 
$$(x_i) = (x_i') = 1, 1, \dots \\ (y_i) = 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0, \dots  \\ (y_i') = 0.5, 0, 0, \dots$$
to get $f_2 = f_2' = 0.25$ but $f_1 = 0.7$ and $f_1' = 0.5$. So the value of $f_1$ does not depend on value of $f_2$.

The result, of course, also holds in $(0, 1)$. But the numbers aren't as easy. I'll leave it for you to find what they are. Ans to show that $f_2$ does not depend on $f_1$.